# How can I get a picture that is depicted on a slicePlane?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vtk, vtk.js

I'm using the [ImageResliceMapper](https://kitware.github.io/vtk-js/examples/ImageResliceMapper.html) example and I'm running into a problem that I can't extract the image the section plane for further processing

When trying to get PolyData return undefined. I would like to get the image data as in captureNextImage()

Comment: [@Анатолий Дуров](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22369954/%d0%90%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%94%d1%83%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2) It is hard to guess what went wrong without looking at your code.

Comment: @Nikhil Devadiga example ImageResliceMapper is my code

Comment: The example on the website runs fine but your copy of it on your local environment doesn't. So I would like to look at *your* code. Specifically, the line on which the error occurs and the neighbouring lines of code. Second I would like to look at the error in its entirety. Only then can someone make an informed decision on how to solve your error.